Flutter Web Animations Fail on Mobile Devices in Chrome
I am developing a Flutter app that works perfectly on desktop browsers but performs very poorly on mobile devices. Specifically, when I use the Chrome browser's "Toggle device toolbar" feature to simulate a mobile device, even simple code fails to execute properly.
Here is a minimal example that causes issues:
  body: Center(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      child: Lottie.asset('assets/emoji/neutral.json'),
    ),
  ),
);

I downloaded the emoji animations from: https://googlefonts.github.io/noto-emoji-animation/
Problems encountered:
For Lottie assets, I get the following errors:
PersistedScene: is in an unexpected state. Expected one of: PersistedSurfaceState.active, PersistedSurfaceState.pendingUpdate But was: PersistedSurfaceState.released
The following UnimplementedError was thrown during a scheduler callback: Flutter Web does not support the blend mode: BlendMode.clear
I also experience similar issues with Rive animations under this configuration.
What I have tried:

Adjusting widget sizes and using different constraints.
Implementing platform-specific adjustments using kIsWeb.
Error handling to catch and manage rendering issues.
Build the app with this command flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

Request:
I am looking for guidance on how to properly support animations (Lottie and Rive) on Flutter Web, particularly when simulating mobile devices in a browser. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
